# Как починить :hover под мобильные устройства?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, прошу совета.  
Есть выпадающее меню, реализованное через css :hover, т.е. есть пункт меню, при наведении срабатывает hover и подменю у данного пункта меняет свойство display на block, после того как убрали мышь, снова становится none. На обычном ПК все хорошо, но на мобильных из-за отсутствия возможности просто навести данная реализация не работает. Как можно это поправить? Чтобы на мобильных устройствах меню тоже выпадало (сейчас при клике оно выпадает, но сразу же переходит по ссылке на первом пункте). Если же это нереально, то как можно реализовать меню, чтобы оно было выпадающим и работало на всех устройствах (те примеры, что я находил через jquery, не подходят, т.к. там основные пункты меню не работают как ссылки, т.е. при клике на них меню просто выпадает, а нужен переход).

Пример

```
<div class="menu"><ul>
<li><a href="../about">О компании</a><ul><a href="../vakansii" class="pp">Вакансии</a></ul></li>
<li><a href="../work">Проекты</a><ul><a href="../otzyivyi" class="pp">Отзывы</a></ul></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Тут из пункта О компании выпадает Вакансии.

Comment: даже не знаю:)
...попробуйте :hover заменить на :active --но на практике не проверял.

..вообще javascript'ом будет надежнее. jQuare --вообще решит множество таких задачек легко.

Comment: А не могли  бы привести пример? Я, честно говоря, не силен в jquery, все пытаюсь дойти до изучения, но что-то все никак :)  
Про яву думал, чтобы по онклику делать выпад, а при повторном делать переход, но пока не придумал реализацию такой затеи + как это внедрить чисто под мобильные (видимо, по заголовку браузера отдавать разные куски кода вывода меню).

Comment: Да, да, как раз пилю пример.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Проблема актуальна, можно решать таким образом:

```
<div class="top-menu" data-hover="hover-on-menu">
<a href="/to/your/url" data-hover="hover-on-link">Hello</a>

<script>

var touchHover = function() {
    $('[data-hover]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var onHover = $this.attr('data-hover');
        var linkHref = $this.attr('href');
        if (linkHref && $this.hasClass(onHover)) {
            location.href = linkHref;
            return false;
        }
        $this.toggleClass(onHover);
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() { touchHover(); });

</script>
```

Даем объектам атрибут data-hover с наименованием класса, который отображает состояние hover этого элемента, в дополнение проверяем на ссылку, если ссылка то переходим "по второму клику".

Comment: @Олег Б, спасибо, теперь все работает как нужно )
___


@Олег Б, к сожалению, лайкнуть ответ не хватает рейтинга )

Comment: @Олег Б, небольшое замечание, лучше использовать $this.data('hover') вместо attr.

Comment: Вот не поверите, @eicto, однажды столкнулся с проблемой, что `data` при наличии верного data-атрибута возвращало `undefined`, а attr('data-название') возвращало корректное значение, и зарекся больше никогда не использовать `$('#id').data('name');`

Answer (score 1):

И так... я не программист, а скорее дизайнер, но вот что у нас получилось, и вроде бы рабочее:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>hi</title>

<style>/*тестовые стили... как и все тут*/
    .menu{
        background: rgba(100,100,100,0.5);

        width: 80%;
        height: 2em;

        margin: 0px auto;

        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
    .menu li{
        background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);

        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 150px;

        font-size:14px;

        overflow: hidden;

        float: left;

        padding: 0.25em;
        margin: 0.25em;

    }
    .menu li a{
        color: black;
    }

    .drop_down ul{
        background: rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
        overflow: hidden;

         transition: height 0.5s 0.2s ease-out;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s 0.2s ease-out;
                -moz-transition: all 0.5s 0.2s ease-out;
                    -o-transition: all 0.5s 0.2s ease-out;
                        -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    }

    .close{/*состояние если закрыт*/
        opacity:0;
        height:0px;
    }
    .drop_down:hover ul, .open{/*состояние если открыт*/
        opacity:1;
        height:auto;

    }

    .drop_down:after{
    /*Это что бы по клику сразу же не переходил по ссылке, а дождался открытия категории*/

    content: "";
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: red;
    opacity:0;
    position: absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;

        /*отсрочка анимации, что бы срабатывал не моментально, а с задержкой*/
        transition:all 1s 1s ease-out;
        -webkit-transition:all 1s 1s ease-out;
            -moz-transition:all 1s 1s ease-out;
                -o-transition:all 1s 1s ease-out;
                    -ms-transition:all 1s 1s ease-out;
}

.drop_down:hover:after{
    /*улетаем далеко и сиангулируем*/
    top:-1000px;
    height:0px;
}

    .drop_down:before{

    /*полезно показать, что что то тут вываливается*/

    content: "";
    display: block;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;

    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #000;

    position: absolute;
        right:10px;
        top: 0.85em;

        opacity:0.5;

        transform: rotate(180deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(180deg);

        transition:all 0.3s 0.1s ease-out;
            -webkit-transition:all 0.3s 0.1s ease-out;
                -moz-transition:all 0.3s 0.1s ease-out;
                    -ms-transition:all 0.3s 0.1s ease-out;
                        -o-transition:all 0.3s 0.1s ease-out;
}

.drop_down:hover:before{

        transform: rotate(0deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
                    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
                        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);

        opacity:0.9;
        top:0.5em;
}

    .drop_down ul li{
        background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);

    }
    .drop_down ul li a{
        color:#fff;
    }

</style>
    </head>
<body>

<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
    <li class="drop_down"><!--на выпадающее меню вешаем дропдаун класс-->
        <a href="#">Выпадающее меню</a>
        <ul class="close"><!-- вставляем наш второй уровень с классом "закрыт" -->
                <li><a href="#">Пункт A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
        var  close_open = false;//переменная закрыт-открыт(...там какой то есть недачет в таком подходе, но я забыл какой. ...но оно работает)
    $( ".drop_down" ).click(function() {//если кликнули по дропдауну, то если переменная close-open равна ложь, то открыть меню(удалить класс close, добавить класс open), присвоив переменной true. открыли.
        if(close_open == false){
            $( ".drop_down ul" ).removeClass("close").addClass("open");
            close_open=true;
        }else{//если переменная true, то мы удаляем класс open, добавлям класс close. закрыли
            $( ".drop_down ul" ).removeClass("open").addClass("close");
            close_open=false; // присвоили переменной false. меню ведь закрыто теперь.
        }
    });

    $( "body" ).click(function() {
//тут я не очень разобрался. в мобилках логает механизм закрытия. поэтому я дополнительно говорю, если кликнуть на body то что бы все закрылось. ...но как правило под курсором не body, а какой то левй контейнер или сложная структура. ...поэтому я хз, как тут поступить.
        $( ".drop_down ul" ).removeClass("open").addClass("close");
            close_open=false;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Идея с active провалилась. При клике, конечно, у нас блок появляется, но как только отпустить курсор (а может быть, и палец), все пропадает. Была идея сделать задержку анимацией, но, что-то там не срослось.

Comment: Спасибо за пример, но все равно не работает так, как я хочу ) на ПК все выпадает, проблем нет, но на мобильном при клике на "Выпадающее меню" оно раскрывается и сразу же уходит по ссылке, т.е., видимо, нужно при первом клике раскрыть и при втором клике уже уходить, а не сразу. Попробую как-то допилить ваш пример )

Comment: > оно раскрывается и сразу же уходит по ссылке

    e.preventDefault() 

Если раскрываем.

Comment: Как вариант, предлагаю ссылку сделать неактивной, а как заголовок раздела.   Опять же зависит от идеи дизайна\юзабилити интерфейса.

Но кодом сейчас еще попробую допилить пример. Идея такова: элементом :after заполнить ячейку и сделать ее прозрачной, заблокировав ссылку, но меню мы развернем. А потом мы спрячем этот элемент, и ссылка будет доступной.
___

upd:
Исправил ситуацию мгновенного перехода на мобильниках. + добавил треугольник сбоку :)

Comment: eicto спасибо за метод, видимо через него и работали все найденные мной примеры, раз там ссылки основных пунктов не переходили, может получится применить
silksOfTheSoul сейчас посмотрю новый вариант ваш, у меня тоже была такая идея, основной пункт меню оставить без выпадалки, а рядом сделать стрелочку чтобы кликали и раскрывали ) но в любом случае сейчас буду разбираться с вашими решениями, т.к. иных вариантов решения проблемы я не нашел )

Comment: @Stuf, как у вас дела? У вас получилось?

Comment: @silksOfTheSoul, да, большое спасибо, что первым откликнулись и сделали рабочее решение, обновленный пример работает как надо ) но я воспользовался примером @Олег Б, т.к. в моем случае требовало меньше правок в код )
___
@silksOfTheSoul, к сожалению, лайкнуть ответ не хватает рейтинга )

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить кнопку-стрелочку, по которой бы открывалось подменю на мобильных экранах

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Прочитал вопрос... Да, вроде ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Лично я не нашел универсального вменяемого решения с использованием :hover для мобильных устройств, поэтому сделал следующее.
Заменил в стилях сss псевдокласс ':hover' на класс '.hover',
а для всех элементов, где надо использовать визуальный эффект добавил класс 'unhover':

```html
<div class="red button unhover">Поехали</div>
```

Далее, вживляем js скрипт (в данном случае с использованием jQuery):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.unhover').click(function(){
$(this).addClass('hover');
setTimeout("jQuery('.unhover').removeClass('hover')", 500);
 });
});
```

И вуаля! Доп. класс живет у нас ровно 500 мс и обеспечивает необходимые эффекты.

Answer (score 0):

В одну строку кода:

```
onmouseover="document.getElementById('sub_menu').style.display='block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('sub_menu').style.display='none'"
```

Comment: Извините, но вместо фраз не имеющих никакого отношения к вопросу, лучше оставить небольшое пояснение к коду предложенному вами как решение.