# Hover на смартфонах

Tags: css3, html5

На пк :hover работает как необходимо. Но вот на смартфонах, прикосновениях, срабатывает но не возращает на исходные свойства.

Есть ли решение, чтобы и на пк работало как необходимо и на тачах.

Comment: Снова гадать по кофейной гуще о Вашей реализации описанного?

Comment: На смартфонах, при прикосновении срабатывает hover, допустим изменили цвет фона. Только он не возвращается на исходный когда прикосновения нет(после нажатия)

Comment: Может это? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/360086/Как-починить-hover-под-мобильные-устройства

Comment: если память не изменяет как минимум на некоторых тачах(на всех или нет не помню) hover срабатывает не ПРИ прикосновении, а до него(когда палец держишь над нужным элементом). а на счет возврата к исходным свойствам, убедитесь что всякие :focus, :visited, :checked и т.п. не подливают масла в огонь(не предоставили код - получайте гадание на кофейной гуще вместо ответа:3 )

Answer (score 0):

**нужно нажать вне объекта**. У меня этих :hover целый сайт [Тихомир](https://seregasmyfavoritesites.on.drv.tw/Site/Tihomir/), штук 100
Кстати, я тоже страдаю от  проблем на мобильных . Пока ничего сделать не могу.

Пробуй вставить в основной класс объекта "обратку". Она возвращает ВСЕ свойства к исходному состоянию.

```
.object {transition: 1s ease}
```

ease — не обязательна, или другой timing

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).